# How to include libraries in Visual Studio automatically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

ALWAYS when I start a new class (EX: main.cpp) I need to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
```

There is a way to make it automatically ? I mean every time when I create a new class they will already be included ?

Answer (score 0):

- A cpp file is not a class, it's a source file. A cpp file may include a class, or multiple classes, or no classes. Similar, a header filer is not a librarie, it's just a header file.
- Add your includes to a header (.h file), and then your cpp file only has to include that single header to include all those common includes. Visual Studio even has something called a precompiled header, which is exactly meant as such a header with common includes, except that it's precompiled (which means, using that will compile faster than using a regular header). Afaik, you'll still have to include that single header yourself, tho, so you won't get around writing at least one `#include ...`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. Sorry im still new programming

Answer (score 0):

My solution is more a workaround than a "real" solution but : You need these lines at least once in your program.
So I'd create a `headers_container.hpp` file containing stuff my whole program needs, like these `#include`.
For example :
`headers_container.hpp` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
// Some stuff my whole program needs...
```

in your `*.cpp` files :

```
#include "headers_container.cpp"
// Your compiler knows iostream, std::strings and math now
```

Make sure the path to `headers_container.hpp` is correct (if the `.hpp` is not in the same folder as your `.cpp`
Using this method, you can add one `#include` in `headers_container.hpp` and it will update all the `.cpp` files.

Moreover you can write a small script to generate files (I did the script you can find here : https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2033889 )
Enjoy your way in programming ! :)

Comment: Broh! u == God 
Thank you sooo much <3

Comment: You're welcome :) If the answer solved your problem, can you upvote and mark my answer as solution please ? Thank you